# How to store crypto pbkdf2 in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following function to hash a user's password, following Express's example for authentication:

```
function hash(pwd, salt, fn) {
    // Bytesize
    var len = 128,

    // Iterations. ~300ms
        iterations = 12000;

    if (3 == arguments.length) {
        crypto.pbkdf2(pwd, salt, iterations, len, fn);
    } else {
        fn = salt;
        crypto.randomBytes(len, function(err, salt){
            if (err) return fn(err);
            salt = salt.toString('base64');
            crypto.pbkdf2(pwd, salt, iterations, len, function(err, hash){
                if (err) return fn(err);
                fn(null, salt, hash);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The `salt`, as you can see, is returned as a string encoded in base64. The `hash`, however, is returned as a `SlowBuffer`. This same function is also used to compare hashes when trying to log a user in.

My Mongoose schema for Users specifies that the `hash` should be of type `String`. This ends up storing the hash in a strange way, resulting in contents like this which wreaked havoc on my mongo host:

[image: screenshot of hash in mongodb]

My question is, is there a better/smarter way to store this `hash` in my database? I've tried encoding it with `.toString('hex')`, and I've also tried changing the `hash` type in the User schema to `buffer`, but both these approaches made all comparisons false when trying to log users in. Comparisons are made in my `authenticate` function, seen below:

```
function authenticate(name, pass, fn) {
    var findUser = function(username) {
        var deferred = Q.defer(),
            populateObj = [
                // list of paths to populate objects normally goes here
            ];
        User.findOne({ username: name }).populate(populateObj).exec(function (err, retrievedUser) {
            if (err || !retrievedUser) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject('Cannot find user.');
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve(retrievedUser);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    findUser(name).then(function(data) {
        // apply the same algorithm to the POSTed password, applying
        // the hash against the pass / salt, if there is a match we
        // found the user
        hash(pass, data.salt, function(err, hash){
            if (err) return fn(err);
            if (hash == data.hash) return fn(null, data);
            return fn('Invalid password.');
        });
    }, function() {
        return fn('Failed to retrieve user.');
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you perform the actual comparisons? Can you show the code for those?

Comment: @robertklep edited to add `authenticate` function, which does the comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the hash as a hex string in the database works okay for me (storing them 'raw' in either a `String` or a `Buffer` property doesn't):

```
var crypto      = require('crypto');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var client      = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var UserSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
  salt  : String,
  hash  : String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

hash('secret', function(err, salt, key) {
  new User({ salt : salt, hash : key.toString('hex') }).save(function(err, doc) {
    User.findById(doc._id, function(err, doc) {
      hash('secret', doc.salt, function(err, key) {
        console.log('eq', doc.hash === key.toString('hex'));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

(by the way, both `crypto.pbkdf2` and `crypto.randomBytes` have synchronous counterparts)

Comment: This worked. When I tried this before, I must not have been calling `toString('hex')` when attempting to log the user in. Also, I know they have synchronous counterparts, I use them in another part of the app. Thank you!